# How to make more posts/data appear on instagram

Tags: node.js, api, instagram

I'm using this url: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/meugatonovet/?__a=1, to get hashtag data. With this parameter it shows a json, but returns only 39 posts/pots of 7,000 thousand.

Is there a tool, some parameter or something else that can make it return more data?

Answer (score 1):

This endpoint is not working anymore:

```
https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/username/?__a=1
```

However, a possible solution is adding `__d=dis` to your payload:

```
https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/username/?__a=1&__d=dis
```

Please, take into account that this is an unofficial method, and you can get banned as @jnv advised.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Using `?__a=1` parameter is a neat trick to get JSON data for any Instagram page, but it's not an official API; Instagram can block your IP address any time and the endpoint is not guaranteed to remain stable.

The official way to look up media via hashtag is with [Graph API Hashtag Search](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/hashtag-search/).

See [getting started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started) for initial steps. You need a business account ID for your Instagram profile which is required parameter for hashtag search. Then you can do these steps:

1. Find the ID of the hashtag you are looking for, for example:

   ```
   GET https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/ig_hashtag_search?user_id=<business account ID>&q=meugatonovet&access_token=<user access token>
   ```

   This will return a JSON of the hashtag:

   ```
   {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "17878113037414936"
      }
    ]
   }
   ```
2. Use that ID in other requests, for example [/recent_media](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-hashtag/recent-media):

   ```
   GET https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/17878113037414936/recent_media?user_id=<business account ID>&fields=id,media_type,comments_count,like_count,media_url&access_token=<user access token>
   ```

   The response will also provide the pagination cursor which lets you read all the data within API limitations.

Other less official options are web scraping or using Instagram's private API (there are actively maintained libraries for that, like [instagram-private-api](https://github.com/dilame/instagram-private-api)), but mind that this might get you banned and it breaks Instagram's ToS. It's probably fine for a personal project, but not so fine for a commercial use.